# What is the difference between 没有+V. and 没+V.?

Tags: difference, past-tense

What is the difference between this two constructions:

> **S + 没有 + V** and  **S + 没 + V**

E.g. 我没有输 and 我没输

As it was mentioned by @user6065 `grammars, e.g. 实用现代汉语语法 make no difference between meaning and usage of adverbs 没 and 没有`, is there any difference in intonation the usage of 没有 has? May be one is preferable in spoken/in written/in official usage?

Comment: grammars, e.g. 实用现代汉语语法 make no difference between meaning and usage of adverbs 没 and 没有

Comment: Evidently there is the special case of V=有，＂实用现代汉语语法＂常用副词的用法，十五、不、没（有）（二）没（有）＂没＂或＂没有＂可用于否定存在、领有以及动作行为的发生、完成。１。否定存在、领有。例如：（１）我没有汽车、没有洋房，算什么大款？（肯定式：有汽车、有洋房）（２）屋子里没有人，好像发生了什么事情。（肯定式：有人）（３）你看，院子里没有一点儿东西，都搬走了。（肯定式：有东西）２。否定动作行为的发生或完成。例如：（１）昨天没下雪。（２）以前，我没学过汉语。（３）那次会议我们没派人参加。（４）那次去泰山，我们没有看到日出的奇景。（５）我没听说过这样的事情。（６）都１０点多了，爸爸还没有回来。（７）我还没有接到回信呢。（８）已经十二月了，河里的水还没有结冰。当＂没有＂用在谓语动词或谓语形容词前时，是副词。当＂没有＂用在名词、数量词前时，＂没＂是副词，＂有＂是动词，其后的名词或数量词语是宾语。

Comment: Many vocabularies has a shortened form. 探望 -> 探，知道 -> 知，前往 -> 往. The meaning is not changed, but there are some subtle differences on rules to use it.

Answer (score 3):

> [沒+ X(v)]  is the negative form of [有+ X(v)] (replace 有 with 沒)

Example:

[**沒**殺人] (did not kill someone)

[**有**殺人]( have killed someone / did kill someone)

*Replace **有** with **沒**

> [沒有+ X(v)] is  also the negative form of [有+X(v)] (add 沒 before 有)

Example:

[**沒**有殺人] (did not kill someone)

[有殺人]( have killed someone / did kill someone)

*Add **沒** before 有

Simply put,  沒 can be used as the shortened form of 沒有

You can also see it as:  "to turn [有+ X(v)] into negative, you can either replace **有** with **沒** or add **沒** before 有"

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me 沒有 is more formal, and 沒 is ellipsis form. I don't think they exhibit difference in usage, though. Note that 沒有 may either be "do not have/possess" (something) or "not" (adverb), depending on context. Chinese is pretty vague sometimes. Lastly, remark that, following the instance 有殺人, “有” is not mandatory and serves as a stressing word.