# "I didn't buy that" without 了

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is 了 ever/sometimes/never omitted for past subjunctive?  What if not subjunctive; i.e., positively something did happen.

wohok.com gives for 没 two example sentences

```
我没买这个
我没有买这个
```

and translates both as "I didn't buy this."  (Could argue this is not subjunctive, but I am familiar with languages where a negative is always subjunctive.

——————

Aside …

[What is the difference between 没有+V. and 没+V.?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22524/what-is-the-difference-between-%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89v-and-%E6%B2%A1v) answers that there is no practical difference between 没有 and 没, but a comment suggests subtle differences in meaning or connotation.  (Have to translate a lot of Chinese to figure out what it is saying!)

Comment: Yes, one of my questions _was_ duplicate before edit, though it will take me time to understand.  (The duplicate suggester is almost never helpful; how do you guys find them?). The other question _remains_ after edit.

Comment: I think the question is very good. The role of 了 in Chinese is strange to say the least. Generally, Chinese people I ask would not use '了' in '我没有买。' but they might end with '啊 or 呀' Cf. ‘我不（想）买了。’I don't （want） to buy (that, it). = I won't buy that.' You might say: '汉语好奇怪啊！‘ but not '汉语好奇怪了’！:)

Comment: @伟思礼 What languages have negative = always subjunctive?

Comment: Well, maybe _usually_ subjunctive in Romance languages.

Comment: It means Finished, or you idea changed.

Answer (score 1):

了 never appears in past negation.

By definition, one of 了 grammatical functions is to indicate **completed action**, and not past tense. Hence, if the action did not happen at all (没), it has also never been **completed**.

> 他还没来 - He still didn't come (and not`他还没来了`）

A side note to that is that 了 would appear in **present** negation.

> 他不来了 - He is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

regarding 了 and negation note e.g. http://human.bsru.ac.th/e-learning/@PWP%20to%20PDF/57%20PDF%20Chiness/57%20Chiness%20Nongnut%202104308.pdf

3）否定句中

♥ 否定句中，“没”与“了”不能同时出现。

♥ 我吃完饭了。→我没吃完饭。→*我没吃完饭了。

♥ 注意：动词前有表示一段时间的词语，句末可用语
气助词“了”。

♥ 我好长时间没看到他了。

♥ 他好久没上班了。

♥ 一年多没回家乡了。

naturally still applies to conditional clauses corresponding to English past subjunctive mood 过去虚拟语气:if I had not bought that 要是我没（有）买这个 (w/o 了）
naturally 过 is possible (要是)我没（有）买过这个

to find more articles concerning absence of 了 in negative clauses search web using e.g. 汉语语法：动态助词＂了＂ 用法与意义＋否定句，get e.g. http://www.cim.chinesecio.com/hbcms/f/article/info?id=3c85e3090860428da0854f5fbab24aa5 : (三)否定句和疑问句

1.带有表示完成的“了”的句子的否定形式是没(有)+ 谓语动词注意：在用“没”的句子里,不可以再出现“了”。

2.问句比较容易,用“吗”的疑问句和正反疑问句。如：他写了三个汉字吗？

他写没写三个汉字？

for English could google "Chinese grammar: aspect particle 了: negation"  get e.g. http://intensive-chinese.blogspot.com/2012/01/used-as-aspect-particle-and-as-modal.html (f) If you want turn an affirmative sentence which contains the aspect particle “了” into a negative sentence, you can do so by prefixing the adverb “没有” to the verb whilst dropping the aspect particle, e.g.:
       他      吃了 晚饭 就 去 看 电影。
       他 没有 吃   晚饭 就 去 看 电影。

We should never use “不” to negate a verb in the past tense or present perfect tense. For this purpose, we use  “没有”; and when using “没有” , we also drop “了” .

Comment: Not sure how long it will take an English speaker to learn from something written in Chinese for Thai speakers.

Comment: text does not seem to reveal that it might be addressed to Thai speakers, anyhow it states a well known fact that can easily be found in any grammar

Comment: Easily?  Perhaps easy for Chinese speakers.  I assume it's directed at Thai speakers because it comes from Thailand and has some Thai in it.